# C# Excel Addin used like formula

Tags: c#, excel, add-on, excel-addins

Ok so I am developing an Excel addin that analyzes text in a cell then converts it.

I want it to work like things do in excel like absolute value when you can type into a cell `=abs(YOURNUMBER)` and then it will replace the text of the cell with the absolute value of your number.

How do i set up the excel add in to add a custom option that would accept strings in a fashion like this, except using `=molem(YOURSTRING)` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make an Excel user-defined function (UDF) using C#. The best way to do this is to use the free [Excel-DNA](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) library (which I develop). This will allow code like this:

```
[ExcelFunction(Description="My clever function")]
public static string molem(string input)
{
    return "You passed " + input;
}
```

to be used in your worksheet as `=molem("Some String")`.